# Storage Concepts iOS - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, storage

I am looking for a storage concept to make a predefined list and values for the list items.

Let me point it out more in details:

We are having a club and we want to add static information like history in years and therefore I want to structure it as following:

```
year 2001 -> events -> event details
year 2002 -> events -> event details
.
.
.
year 2015 -> events -> event details
```

I am already aware of core-data -> can I prefill that?
I am already aware of SwiftyJSON -> nope, I want the data offline
NSUserDefaults if not what I want.

Comment: If you have large amount of data, core data is the way to go and yes, you can [preload the data in a coredata sqlite db](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated). However, if you have limited amount of data you can always [use plist files](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html).

Comment: thank you. If you post an answer I will upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have large amount of data, core data is the way to go and yes, you can [preload the data in a core data sqlite db](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated).

However, if you have limited amount of data you can always [use plist files](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html). You can directly read-write plist files to and from NSArray and NSDictionary objects and you can directly work with dictionaries with standard key strings for each event detail.

**NOTE:** *Your app logic will break if you accidentally use wrong keys in plist. You'd be better off using core data or even simple sqlite db without core data if your data set is large, complex or managed by multiple developers.*